# It's possible an lambda function schedule another function execution?

Tags: aws-lambda, schedule, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have this one function that is triggered every time an user quits the chat withouth properly ending the attendance. I want to know if its possible this function of mine create an schedule to execute another function to alert the user about the unfinished attendance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do using [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html).

You can configure a state machine in which depending on the return value of your first lambda, a [wait state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) will occur and afterward another lambda will be invoked.

Comment: I was trying to make it through the Cloudwatch event, will take a look on this! Thanks!

Comment: It solved my problem and open new horizon for some features i was having some trouble to design. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped. This feature is very useful for Serverless applications